# Retrieve All subscribers related to a child BU only

Tags: marketing-cloud

- All subscribers is a list at enterprise level and is shared across all child BUs
- [BusinessUnitUnsubscribes](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_data_view_businessunitunsubscribes.htm&type=5) allows to get unsubscribes per child BU, assuming "*Subscribers will be unsubscribed from this BU only*" is set in **setup** > **Business units** > **Unsubscribes settings**

objective: retrieve all subscribers emails related to that child BU.
This is the audience we reach out when sending to "all subscribers" from email studio.

ENT._Subscribers will return all subscribers from all BUs instead, but not for the child BU.
Still this audience exists somewhere since we can send to "All subscribers".

- No master DE in the child BU

Comment: Do you have a Master DE in each child BU?

Comment: Check this out, https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_subscribers_extract.htm&type=5
I'm not a 100% if it's what you are looking for

Comment: Also, If you have your contacts in a master DE in the child BU you can try to join with ent._subscribers.

Comment: specific question for my better understanding:  If I understand correctly, you are looking for _All records with a current status of "active" as displayed on All Subscribers in your child BU_?

Comment: I dont have a master DE in the child BU. I try to get all contacts related to the child BU, that were added to the All Subscribers (whatever the status).  --> From email studio there is the possibility to send to "All Subscribers". this is precisely this list of contacts I try to query (retrieve)