# Create a Master DE of Subscribers in a Child BU

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, dataextensions, data-views, sfmc-business-unit

**Hangup:** We have four separate "master DE's" being imported from IT into our marketing child business unit, each segmenting customers a different way. There is overlap between the four.

**Goal:** Create one unified Master DE for the marketing child BU that has subscriber status and engagement, which can then be joined with other DE's as necessary. I'm able to make one that pulls in the entire enterprise list, but that mixes HR with marketing and is not ideal.

There was a previous question with the same goal, but it was never fully answered.
[Retrieve All subscribers related to a child BU only](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/326663/65563)

**Update:** Would it be easier to add the engagement data on each of the four individual DE's directly instead?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "engagement data"?

Comment: @AdamSpriggs - Date joined, last sent date, last open date, and last click date. I think our rewards team is planning on using the info for reengagement and list cleanup.

Comment: The data views are per BU, so do I'd suggest aggregating there.  You could do it at the parent but with tracking data extracted and imported, but it doesn't scale very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me like you need an automation in each business unit (with staggered schedules) to update a shared data extension.

In an Enterprise 2.0 account, subscribers are shared across all business units.  The platform only keeps track of unsubscribes per business unit.  So the concept of business unit membership is convoluted, because it's technically "all" unless they've opted out at the business unit level.

For those subscribers who've been sent an email, you can determine BU-level subscriber status using an automation [like this](https://sprignaturemoves.com/determining-business-unit-subscriber-status/) in the parent BU.

1. Assign all subscribers to all business units
2. Mark unsubscribes per business unit

I'd suggest maintaining a centralized BU status DE in shared and joining your Master DEs to it in order to retrieve the BU status.

The "and engagement" part is generally very heavy lift, since you'll have to aggregate it by subscriber using a series of queries in each BU.